# How can I set a limitation for one column on all SQL selects?

Tags: sql, select

We have a database that holds data for numerous customers. We want to give customers access to the database, but only to the data that belongs to them. Parsing the select to then insert in the where clause "and Company.Name = 'Acme'" strikes me as weak because SQL selects can be very complex and handling 100% of all cases may be difficult.

Is there some way to do the equivalent of (I know this is not valid SQL):

select * from * where Company.Name = 'Acme' and (passed_in_select)

You can nest a full select in as an inner part of a large select. Is there some way to do the above? This way it's a very simple restriction on the select and that is likely to work 100% of the time.

Comment: Are you really wanting the customer to access your database server or are you wanting them to have access to data through a website or an application?

Comment: what database system?

Comment: @zedfoxus It will always be through our reporting system so via an application that can change the selects as they are passed in.

Comment: @PavelGatnar - Any SQL database.

Comment: added WITH clause solution to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a system solution called "virtual private database" for Oracle database:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm

For other databases look whether there is similar built-in solution.

But there is very simple solution using the WITH clause:

```
WITH
  tab_a__ AS (SELECT * FROM tab_a WHERE comp="xy"),
  tab_b__ AS (SELECT * FROM tab_b WHERE comp="xy")
SELECT ... //original select
```

You just have to find all used tables in the select, add `__` behind and add the CTEs to the WITH clause.
Notes: Some databases do not support WITH clause though it is an SQL standard. Some databases can have alias length limitation you could exceed by adding the suffix.

Comment: That looks perfect for Oracle. For others we'll have to do the same ourselves. thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(
  select * from table_a
) outer_table_a
where outer_table_a.col_a = 'test'
```

I do this sort of thing often especially when I want to perform some aggregation on the data in the inner query (sum, max, etc.)  I do this with SQL Server, I do not know if it is valid with other DBMS but I would be surprised if it were not.

I don't know if I would rely on this approach to effectively grant permissions.  Perhaps views would allow you lock things down a bit tighter.  It sounds like you're planning to tack something on dynamically to a query that you may not have written?  In that case whomever writes that query could transform your column of interest which would result in visibility over things you didn't intend, like:

```
select * from
(
  select 'test' as col_a, launch_codes from table_a
) outer_table_a
where outer_table_a.col_a = 'test'
```

Comment: Couldn't I use "where real_table_name.col_a = 'test'" to avoid the renaming issue you listed?